# How to fix broken indention on copy/paste Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode11, auto-indent

After upgrading xcode to v.11 my indention is off when I copy/paste code. The example below shows how it looks when I copy a code. Does anybody know how to fix this?

```
public func configure(_ view: WithdrawelView) {
        view.paySumLabel.text = self.pay
        view.expensesSumLabel.text = self.expenses
        view.refundSumLabel.text = self.refund
        view.taxLastYearSumLabel.text = self.taxLastYear
        view.futureWithdrawelSumLabel.text = self.futureWithdrawel
        view.balanceSumLabel.text = self.balance
    }
public func configure(_ view: WithdrawelView) {
           view.paySumLabel.text = self.pay
           view.expensesSumLabel.text = self.expenses
           view.refundSumLabel.text = self.refund
           view.taxLastYearSumLabel.text = self.taxLastYear
           view.futureWithdrawelSumLabel.text = self.futureWithdrawel
           view.balanceSumLabel.text = self.balance
       }
```

Comment: CMD + A (to select all code) or highlight the code you wish to format, then CTRL + i (this formats the code).

Comment: yes, select code that you want to do indentation and press CTRL + i

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to Preferences -> Text Editing -> Indentation and check "Re-indent on paste"

Comment: Thank you. You also have to have turn on "Indent when typing" and choose an appropriate set of symbols for your language. This is crazy, of course, because I don't want to "re-indent" with a new set of rules, I want whatever indentation I just copied! But it's the best answer we've got at the moment.

Comment: THANK YOU ! this should be accepted  this issue was driving me nuts for month, didn't know there was an option for this. thanks mate

Answer (score 4):

Select the code in question and use `ctrl+i` to auto indent the selected code.

Comment: But that doesn't solve the underlying problem of that the indention changes on copy/paste, where before the update it didn't

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where pasted code would mysteriously be indented 3 spaces instead of 4, making it subtly "wrong" and causing anal-retentive me to waste time re-indenting.

Re-indent on paste didn't work for me, it just removes indentation entirely and pastes the entire block at the same indentation, regardless of brackets/previous indentation.

What did work for me is switching to tabs from spaces in Preferences->Text Editing->Indentation, and turning off Re-indent. Now everything maintains proper indentation, but is pasted one level too deep which is much easier to fix (select block, command-[).